# Why OpenCV's `cvCreateCameraCapture` and `cvCreateFileCapture` do not work?

Tags: c++, video, opencv, webcam, video-capture

Have an AVI videofile, and a webcam. `cvQueryFrame` returns null in both cases. Code is applied(only for cam):

```
#include "highgui.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{   
    cvNamedWindow( "KillCam", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvWaitKey(0);
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(-1);
    assert(capture != NULL);
    IplImage* frame;

    while(1){
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture ); 
        if( !frame ) break;
        cvShowImage( "KillCam", frame );
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if( c == 30 ) break;
    }
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    cvDestroyWindow( "KillCam" );
}
```

Comment: Just a hunch: try using index 0 for the camera. Also check that your camera is properly installed (can you use it from applications?) And that no other application is currently using the camera.

Comment: Found the solution already. It seems that first frame(s) are not not displayed so `if( !frame ) break;` terminates the viewing of the video before it starts. But the problem is still relevant for retrieving video from file.

Answer (score 3):

I found, by stepping into the openCV code, that I needed to ensure the fmpeg dll was present in the current working directory at runtime:

```
opencv_ffmpeg200d.dll
```

OpenCV doesn't shed any warning if this dll is not found, instead the capture create call just returns NULL.

hth

Si

Comment: I downloaded the precompiled OpenCV2.4.2 and this debug file doesn't come included. The opencv_ffmpef242.dll comes. The thing is that I cannot build my libraries (yet) as I have no free space in the hard drive...

Answer (score 0):

Check the video format.  OpenCV can be picky in which codecs it supports; it doesn't work with Xvid, for example.  You can find a list of supported codecs on the [OpenCV wiki](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoCodecs)