# VideoCapture OpenCV 2.4.2 error in windows

Tags: opencv

I have a problem using VideoCapture class with OpenCV 2.4.2 under windows XP 32bits.
It doesn't open any file or camera and fixing it's being a pain.
Im using visual studio 2010 but i have also tried the code in QTcreator with the same result.

The testing code is the following:

```
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <sstream> 

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char* videoPath = "C:/video/";
    string videoName = string(videoPath) + "avi.avi";
    VideoCapture cap(videoName);

    if(!cap.isOpened()) 
    {
        std::cout<<"Fail"<<std::endl;
        return -3;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

The output is always '-3'.
Qt Creator shows a 
    warning: Error opening file (../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:361)

I debugged it and the problem appears in the first line of:

```
CvCapture* cvCreateFileCapture_FFMPEG_proxy(const char * filename)
{
    CvCapture_FFMPEG_proxy* result = new CvCapture_FFMPEG_proxy;
    if( result->open( filename ))
        return result;
    delete result;
#if defined WIN32 || defined _WIN32
    return cvCreateFileCapture_VFW(filename);
#else
    return 0;
#endif
}
```

in the cap_ffmpeg.cpp internal file.

I have tested the same code in a mac under snow leopard and it works. No surprises here since it must be a library issue.
I have opened the avi file with the same path route using the c-function cvCapture easy and fast.
I got all the dlls of 'C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin'
included in mi debug file. I got the tbb.dll and all the 'C:\opencv\opencv\3rdparty\ffmpeg' content included too.

This is drving me crazy so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987782/why-opencvs-cvcreatecameracapture-and-cvcreatefilecapture-do-not-work-how) could be your case: Try copying opencv_ffmpeg242d.dll or opencv_ffmpeg242.dll to your current working directory. Also, have you built OpenCV yourself? Are you sure all the dependencies are ok?

Comment: I still have the same problem. I have read in some forums that maybe updating codecs is needed. I will try that. Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, the same problem was resolved after deleting all `opencv_***.dll` files in `C:\Windows\System32`. So, I use the dll files just through the path like `"%PATH%;C: \Program Files \OpenCV2.4.2\build\x86\vc10/bin"`. Please try it.

Comment: I (conservatively) tried just to move all opencv_*.dll files out of Windows\System32 and also out of Windows\SysWOW64.  Rebooted,still didn't work.  Zipped up the dlls and removed the originals; Rebooted again, this worked great!  So Young-Shik Kwon's suggestion is very good.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced with this problem and solved it by correct the path of the function:

```
VideoCapture cap(videoName);
```

If the AVI file of **videoName** does't exist, it will be an error:

```
(../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:XXX)
```

where XXX represents the line number.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the open method whilst running under Windows 8 (64bit), opencv 2.4.10. IDE is running in x86.

I found that running the application in release configuration solved the problem.

Stumbled across the answer because I had the same issue with imread. Issue is presented in the this thread.
[imread not working in Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417637/imread-not-working-in-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

See the fix I found below, for mp4 files.
I faced the same issue on Windows 7, using OpenCV 2.4.9. I am using the java wrapper for opencv.

Matthias Krings has done a lot of research for this. See [this](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3422). Apparently this is an issue based on the video file type. With .avi files, it seems to work for a lot of people. Unfortunately his solution of setting OPENCV_DIR did not work for me. But his comments in the bug listing gave me a hint to fix the issue.

You have to do two things:

1. Set `java.library.path` to include the directory `{opencv\install\dir}opencv-2.4.9\build\x86\vc10\bin`. You can set the variable using the `-D` option on the java command line: `java -Djava.library.path=PATH_TO_YOUR_DLL ...`. Also fetch this variable from your environment, using `System.getProperty(...)`, and print it before calling `loadLibrary()`, to verify that the path setting is working.
2. And in your java class, load the ffmpeg dll using `System.loadLibrary("opencv_ffmpeg249");`. The `loadLibrary()` function should be invoked from within a `static block` in java.
3. There is a file named `opencv_ffmpeg249.dll` in the `java.library.path` that we set.
4. This works on ubuntu also, for `.so` files.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue and resolved after pointing to the correct location of the input video.