# Video problems with OpenCV 2.4.3

Tags: opencv, video-capture

I am having pretty much the exact problem that was described here:

[VideoCapture OpenCV 2.4.2 error in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279833/videocapture-opencv-2-4-2-error-in-windows)

None of the suggestions provided were helpful, so I thought I would ask again. I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express on Windows 7, but I have also tried Visual Studio 2008 Professional with exactly the same result. I am able to compile and when I run the application, all the DLLs I expect are being loaded (there are no DLLs from other versions of OpenCV being inadvertently loaded). Are there any other things I can do to debug this? I am using a Creative Live! cam socialize HD AF. I think other people have been able to get this camera to work with OpenCV. When I run the following code:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap("0"); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
       {
     cout << "Error opening camera!";
     getchar();
     return -1;
 }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

I always get the following message:

warning: Error opening file (../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:365)
Error opening camera!

I would very much appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a typo? `VideoCapture cap("0");`. It should be `VideoCapture cap(0);`

Comment: You are right. How embarrassing. I am not very familiar with OpenCV, and I was assuming that there was some problem with my configuration, and that examples downloaded off the internet would just work. That fixed my problem. Thanks!