# Opencv VideoCapture: Error opening file

Tags: java, opencv, ffmpeg

I am triyng to capture IP camera video stream by using OpenCV Java. But I got this warning:

> warning: Error opening file
>   (../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:537)

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279833/videocapture-opencv-2-4-2-error-in-windows).But it did not work.

I am using openCV 2.4.11 on Windows 10.
My settings are:

> I loaded the library: C:\opencv2411\opencv\build\java\opencv-2411.jar
>
> Java library path:
>   -Djava.library.path="C:\opencv2411\opencv\build\java\x64"
>   C:\opencv2411\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin and
>   C:\opencv2411\opencv\sources\3rdparty\ffmpeg are added to PATH

```
package opencvApp;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;

public class OpencvApp{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        VideoCapture cap=new VideoCapture();
        cap.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640);
        cap.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,360);
        cap.open("‪C:\\Users\\Berkan\\Videos\\vidm1453499924.mp4");
        //cap.open(0);
        Mat foto = new Mat();
        if (cap.isOpened())
        {
            System.out.println("Video is opened");
            cap.read(foto);
            Highgui.imwrite("C:\\Users\\Berkan\\Desktop\\ada\\foto.png", foto);
            cap.release();
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Fail");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: please provide full stack trace

Comment: The warning I wrote above is the only trace

Comment: It should be the way you load the library. That is not the library name. Should be `opencv_java` try changing that first.